# In 'having trouble -ing', does the 'ing' have progressive meaning?

Tags: progressive-aspect

> But it is clear that a number of major public employers are having trouble **affording** the state’s current pension system.  ([nytimes.com](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/02/28/nyregion/to-pay-new-york-pension-fund-cities-borrow-from-it-first.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0))

When we have *verb-ing* form after *trouble*, does it imply the activity is happening progressively? Or does it only imply there is a specific fact that inflicts hardness and have no on-going meaning of the activity, by the form itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be fooled by the seeming addition of the word "trouble" to the verb "have". Just learn to treat the two words, "**Have trouble**" as if they were a single verb. That way you can *have trouble* the same as you can *enjoy, hate* or *practice*:

- affording things
- swallowing
- understanding

Learn to practice and conjugate "have trouble" and use it spontaneously at your first opportunity. ;-)

Other verbs *don't* go with "..ing" and you will learn to use them separately.

*Note: *It is bad pedagogy for a teacher to introduce to a student two things which mustn't be confused with one another; neither in the same breath, nor on the same page, nor within the same lesson, nor even on the same day! **It only serves to aggravate the student's confusing the two**!*